# Solving trig. equations by dividing and squaring.

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

A problem I'm solving involves a system of the sort :

$G\sin(g)=C$ and  $G\cos(g)=D$ where $ C,D\in\mathbb{R}$ barring $D=0$

I am to find expressions for G and g (in terms of C and D) for any C, D. The method I have been instructed to follow is dividing both equations to get $\tan(g) =\frac{C}{D}$ to find $g$. And to square and add both equations to get $G^2= D^2 + C^2 $ to find $G$. But I've been asked to verify that such a system is always consistent and that our method doesn't lead us astray. I need someone to check my work :

Find $G = \pm\sqrt{C^2 +D^2}$. Now solve for $g$ using the tangent expression. I next reasoned that the values of $g$ found must contain values that satisfy the expressions $\sin(g)=\frac{C}{G},\cos(g)=\frac{D}{G}$ since this is one possibility that leads to $\tan(g)=\frac{C}{D}$. But how can I be sure such $g$ exist? I reasoned that $|G|, C, D$ form sides of a right angle triangle in some quadrant and so we can always find such $g$. Finally, the tan equation has infinite solutions of the form $x+n\pi,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moving from one solution to the next changes the signs on both sine and cosine. This is where I reasoned that the $\pm$ of $G$ comes in.

Is this a valid way to explain the veracity of the method? Where I doubt my reasoning the most is with $G$. To get the expression for $G$, I had to use a trig. identity. So in that step, I basically assume $g$ exists. But I guessed this was not a problem since we later showed that for any C,D our expressions for the solution must work.

Comment: Such a $g$ always exists because $(\sin(x),\cos(x)), x\in[0,2\pi[$ parametrizes the whole unit sphere. You can explicitly plug in $g=\arcsin(C/G)$.

Answer (score 1):

For any pair of values $C$ and $D$, with the exception of $A=B=0$, there is one and only one solution of the system of equations:
$$G\sin(g)=C, G\cos(g)=D, g\in[0,2\pi), G>0$$
First, we solve for $G$, using the trig identity mentioned in the original post.  $G=\sqrt{C^2+D^2}$.  Next, we can solve for $g$ in one of two methods: either using the method discussed in the original post: $g=\tan^{-1}(\frac{C}{D})$ for $D>0$, $g=\pi+\tan^{-1}(\frac{C}{D})$ for $D>0$, $g=\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $C>0,D=0$, and $g=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ for $C<0,D=0$.

We can also solve this in the following method: We can use the signs of $C$ and $D$ to figure out which quadrant $g$ is in, and then use either $g=\sin^{-1}(\frac{C}{G})$ or $g=\cos^{-1}(\frac{D}{G})$.

Whichever method we use to solve for $g$, there are additional answers if we expand to the domain of all real numbers, of the form $g+2n\pi$ for some integer n.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But we have assumed again that the system is consistent. We were asked to check this since if G were not present, it is possible for the tan method to mislead us. Say $sin (g)= 1, cos(g)=0.5$ . The tan method will give answers but none that work. We were asked to reason why the freedom with G allows this method to work.

Comment: @Sal_99: There is a requirement that $\sin^2(g)+\cos^2(g)=1$, no matter what value we choose for $g$.  In the example in your comment, the values for sine and cosine are incompatible.  However, once we include a coefficient $G$, this requirement becomes $G^2\sin^2(g)+G^2\cos^2(g)=G^2$, which always has a positive solution

Comment: Oh I think I get this better now : if $g$ is valid then the trig identity must work. For it to work, $(C/G) ^2 + (D/G)^2 =1 $ . Now we can always find a $G$ such that this works ( barring both C,D=0). So that's it. By picking G appropriately, we know that $g$ exists. I guess this is what I was indirectly referring to with the right angle triangle matter.